# How to update my table using gui using netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql

Code:

```
private void updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try{
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update tender.bidder set bname =?,office=?,street=?,city=?,state=?,contact_no=?,password=?,email=?,t_id=? where b_id = ?");

           // String sql = "update tender.bidder set bname ='"+bnametxt.getText()+"'"+",office ='"+officetxt.getText()+"'"+
           //         ",street ='"+streettxt.getText()+"'"+",contact_no='"+contacttxt.getText()+"'"+",password='"+passwordtxt.getText()+"'"+",email='"+emailtxt.getText()
           //         +"'"+"where b_id ="+bidtxt.getText();
        pstmt.setString(1,bidtxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(2,bnametxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(3,officetxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(4,streettxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(5,citytxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(6,statetxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(7,contacttxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(8,passwordtxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(9,emailtxt.getText());
        pstmt.setString(10,tidtxt.getText());
        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("update tender.bidder set bname ='"+bnametxt.getText()+"'"+",office='"+officetxt.getText()+"'"+",street='"+streettxt.getText()+"'"+",city='"+citytxt.getText()+"'"+",state='"+statetxt.getText()+"'"+",contact_no='"+contacttxt.getText()+"'"+",password='"+passwordtxt.getText()+"'"+",email="+emailtxt.getText()+"'"+",t_id="+tidtxt.getText()+"'"+"where b_id ="+bidtxt.getText());
                 //   +streettxt.getText()+"'"+",city='"+citytxt.getText()+"'"+",state='"+statetxt.getText()+"'"+",contact_no='"+contacttxt.getText()+"'"+",password="+"'"passwordtxt.getText()
                 //   +"'"+",email="+emailtxt.getText()+"'"+",t_id='"+tidtxt.getText() +"'"+"where b_id ="+bidtxt.getText();
           // Statement updt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        System.out.println(i+"record updated");
        con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selectionall();

}
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'B002' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'B002' is not a column in the target table.

Comment: Looks like a issue with Quoting, you probably have forgot to quote the value `B002`

Comment: Its not that dude. The same thing happened for my delete function.There was an error in the preparedstatement and executeUpdate() function.Thank You anyway ))